# 400 bad request for requesting github repos from jenkins blueocean plugin installed on docker

Tags: docker, jenkins, github, jenkins-blueocean

I am trying to make a pipeline with GitHub repo, I made an access key but I get a bad request when I click connect:

```
{
  "message" : "Invalid apiUrl",
  "code" : 400,
  "errors" : [ {
    "message" : "api.github.com",
    "code" : "INVALID",
    "field" : "apiUrl"
  } ]
}
```

The whole configuration installed on localhost

Comment: can you paste your pipeline script here.

Comment: I didn't make a script, I am just connecting blueocean with github repos to choose one of them using token.

Comment: do I need to add a jenkins file to a repo to be loaded?

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved after restarting docker containers!